# automatic deployment of a web project using eclipse maven and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I followed the simple steps, for achieving this. Integrated Tomcat and Maven with eclipse.
1. Open eclipse. New->other -> maven project -> webapp
2. Added plugins for tomcat.
3. Right click the POM file and run as maven clean
4. run as maven generate sources
5. run as maven build.
6. passed the command tomcat:run 
But getting the following error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project simplehelloworld: Could not start Tomcat: Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Did you check that the following posts could help you ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032950/deploying-appfuse-spring-mvc-project-to-tomcat-direcly-from-sts-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674170/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojotomcat-maven-pluginrun

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not start Tomcat: Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
```

above error means that there is already a service running on port 8080. is there a tomcat server running already?

if any service running on 8080 then you close shut it or you need to change the connector configuration in server.xml to something like below :

```
<Connector port="9090" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

you can find if this port already in use or not, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port) link.

Comment: I have checked the port, but nothing is running.

Comment: did you try `mvn tomcat:deploy`?
Note :- with tomcat 7 :- `mvn tomcat7:deploy`  might be eclipse is holding that port, you can try to restart eclipse, if you are sure that this port is not in use by anyother application

Comment: And give a try by using another port. I think then you can have more clear picture of issue.